# cgal: Surface simplification of 3d triangulated mesh

Tags: 3d, cgal

I would like to use the surface simplification algorithm of CGAL with C3t3 (Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3) object.

I have the C3t3 object, how do I use this function with this kind of object. The only examples I found were using Polyhedron objects.

More specifically i need to use the SMS::edge_collapse function

Thanks.

Comment: A c3t3 object does not represent a surface mesh but a volume mesh so you cannot use the collapse_edge function on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `C3t3` object is first a 3D regular triangulation of the set points in the mesh. We cannot collapse edges in a regular triangulation. All you can do is remove or add new points.

I suggest you export the surface of the `C3t3` object to a data structure where you can apply `SMS::edge_collapse`.